# Diagram with diagonal, vertical, horizontal and bent arrows

Tags: tikz-cd

How can I draw the following diagram using `tikz-cd`?

[image]

I've seen a lot of examples on the internet, but none of them helped (actually, they confused me more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
 & A\arrow[d] \arrow[ddl,bend right]\arrow[ddr,bend left] & \\
 & B \arrow[dr] \arrow[dl]& \\
C \arrow[rr]&  & D \\ 
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with some smaller `column sep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1em]
 & A\arrow[d] \arrow[ddl,bend right]\arrow[ddr,bend left] & \\
 & B \arrow[dr] \arrow[dl]& \\
C \arrow[rr]&  & D \\ 
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how the ampersands work here (how many do I need, where do I need them etc)? I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @rmdmc89 `tikz-cd` is basically an extension of the `matrix` library of `tikz`. So you may think of `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` as being arranged in a matrix, and connected by appropriate arrows. The columns of the matrix get separated by `&`, and the rows by `\\ `. In the case at hand, we may want to use a 3x3 matrix. The distances between rows and columns can be changed with `column sep` and `row sep`, respectively.